# Caused by: org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException: Encryption raised an exception

Tags: jasypt

Followed below steps to encrypt the secret, however facing below issue.

1. Add the dependency in your parent pom :

   com.github.ulisesbocchio
       jasypt-spring-boot-starter
       3.0.3
2. Add also the maven plugin just to encrypt the password(s) (it could be removed once the passwords are generated) :

   com.github.ulisesbocchio
     jasypt-maven-plugin
     3.0.3
3. Encrypt your client-secret using the maven plugin :

   mvn jasypt:encrypt-value "-Djasypt.encryptor.password=secretKey" "-Djasypt.plugin.value=secret"

**Issue**:

"Caused by: org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException: Encryption raised an exception. A possible cause is you are using stron`enter code here`g encryption algorithms and you have not installed the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE
) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files in this Java Virtual Machine".

Answer (score 0):

**Resolution**:

As the exception indicates one need to install the latest JCE Policy Jar Files into your JAVA setup.

1. Download the JCE Policy jar files from the below location: (since my java version is 8 I choose **javase-jce8-downloads.html**, please download correct jce files based on your java version)

   https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jce8-downloads.html
2. The zip file would contain two jar files (local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar).
3. These jar files need to be placed under the following location:

   %JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\

Reference : https://technofes.blogspot.com/2011/10/orgjasyptexceptionsencryptionoperationn.html